# Postfix fail2ban help.. I have a bad host but fail2ban won't block him

Tags: centos, postfix, fail2ban

Hi I am using postfix plus fail2ban on Centos 6.5 but I am getting botted (I am not relaying but there you go) and for some reason fail2ban isn't able to cut the ip and block it this is 6/7 times a second going into my `/var/log/maillog`

```
Mar  3 13:05:47 postfix/smtpd[27715]: lost connection after UNKNOWN from Unknown[209.15.212.253]
Mar  3 13:05:47 postfix/smtpd[27715]: disconnect from unknown[209.15.212.253]
Mar  3 13:05:47 postfix/smtpd[27715]: warning: valid_hostname: misplaced delimiter: .
```

I don't have a problem with `publishing` the IP of this bot because it's clearly not friends to anyone and is a purpose built spam engine ip (it RDNS's as a ".", to try to create misplaced delimiter loophole)

anyway I have fail2ban configured fairly right, it emails me to say it is up and running under sasl and postfix

here is the `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`

```
findtime  = 600
bantime  = 600
maxretry = 6


[sasl-iptables]
enabled  = true
filter   = postfix-sasl
backend  = polling
action   = iptables[name=sasl, port=smtp, protocol=tcp]
            sendmail-whois[name=sasl, dest=email@me.com]
logpath  = /var/log/maillog
maxretry = 5
bantime  = 300

[postfix-tcpwrapper]
enabled  = true
filter   = postfix
action   = hostsdeny[file=/not/a/standard/path/hosts.deny]
           sendmail[name=Postfix, dest=email@me.com]
logpath  = /var/log/maillog
bantime  = 300
maxretry = 6

 ##the following are done in sheer desperation - no idea if they are needed
[postfix]
enabled = true
port    = smtp,ssmtp
filter  = postfix
action  = hostsdeny
logpath = /var/log/maillog

[perdition]
enabled = true
filter  = perdition
action  = iptables-multiport[name=perdition,port="110,143,993,995"]
logpath = /var/log/maillog

[dovecot-pop3imap]
enabled = true
port = pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps
filter = dovecot-pop3imap
action  = hostsdeny
logpath = /var/log/maillog
```

Can anyone help me explain why these rules are in yet `/var/logs/maillog` is still being written too all the time, and no-one is being banned?

[/EDIT] being a bit of a noob at fail2ban I didn't realise it (sort of) hand balls every line via regex - here is my `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/postfix.conf`

```
# Fail2Ban filter for selected Postfix SMTP rejections
#
#

[INCLUDES]

# Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from
# common.local
before = common.conf

[Definition]

_daemon = postfix/smtpd

failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)sNOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from \S+\[<HOST>\]: 554 5\.7\.1 .*$
            ^%(__prefix_line)sNOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from \S+\[<HOST>\]: 450 4\.7\.1 : Helo command rejected: Host not found; from=<> to=<> proto=ESMTP helo= *$
            ^%(__prefix_line)sNOQUEUE: reject: VRFY from \S+\[<HOST>\]: 550 5\.1\.1 .*$

ignoreregex =

# Author: Cyril Jaquier
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the useful information which is the relevant regexes.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told us what's in your `postfix` filter, but if your install's anything like mine, it's something like

```
failregex = reject: RCPT from (.*)\[<HOST>\]: 554
```

Since the log lines you've shown us don't look anything like that, `fail2ban` won't be triggering on them.  You will need to write your own filter, that matches those lines, if you want them to trigger a ban.

But you may find that, just to block that single IP address, it's more efficient to put an `iptables` rule in yourself.  Something like

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -s 209.15.212.253 -p tcp --dport 25 -j REJECT
```

would probably do the trick.

Comment: I have posted it in an `edit` of the `OP` - can you help me write a good regex match? I don't want to just `iptables` ban it just yet, i'd rather the bot was autoremoved by `fail2ban` - it's a nice test